# Vaadin7 with grails plugin and ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper

Tags: grails, spring-security, vaadin7

Having an application using Vaadin7 with grails (thanks to Ondrej's plugin). As I'm implementing business logic inside Vaadin components, i'm also interested having an admin console running a classic MVC pattern using grails controller so as to manage users, logs and others events.

Then, in VaadinConfig, I've added the URL mappings to the grails controllers (including spring-security-ui below):

```
  mappingExtras = [
             '/console/*',
             '/user/*',
             '/role/*',
             '/securityInfo/*'
    ]
```

It Works great to display lists and retrieve datas from DB, but fails when i need to pass params to controllers so as to save or update domain objects. Hence I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method name must not be null
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.retrieveAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:41)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:102)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Is there a way to proxify controllers with ease in that case? How to get rid off ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper error and injecting the params ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with my plugin and submitted aJIRA for it. This seems to be related to spring security as you pointed out with your tag. Including the JIRA link if you want to rate it up...

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11461